# What are the required AWS IAM policy permissions to provision EC2 Instances from the CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, roles, amazon-policy

I am writing an IAM Policy to deploy EC2 Instances from the CLI, I don't want to give EC2 full access. Following principle of least privilege, what are the permissions required to provision EC2 Instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on if you want them to lunch from console or CLI.

For console, according to [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-ec2-console.html#ex-launch-wizard) the following policy is suited:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeImages",
                "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:CreateKeyPair"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

For CLI the policies are shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ExamplePolicies_EC2.html#iam-example-runinstances).

Comment: can we have all those permissions under single action, in one statement? without having another statement for RunInstances.

Comment: @sagarmuth Yes. you can make it into one action element.